# ACS Push Notification to Android devices failed with status "Failed (2)"

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow

I was trying to send Push Notification Message to Android devices in Appcelerator Platform, and it was working but suddenly we receive this error in message Status "Failure (2)"

I couldn't find any details about that error neither in the Push Logs nor the App Dashboard Logs.

Comment: Where do you receive this error?

Comment: inside the ACS "Push Log" dashboard

Comment: I've asked an Appcelerator cloud engineer to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs in 2 scenarios:

1. Your certificate has an error
2. There's a network issue between us and Apple or GCM.

The Appcelerator Dashboard will soon be updated to show the exact error code and description when you hover over the failure.

Comment: I am experiencing this error only with Android devices

Comment: Sorry, I meant both Apple or GCM. The Dashboard update is out so you should now see the actual reason. I've also requested for a new feature to easily retry a failed notification.

Comment: Unfortunately we won't be able to offer a retry-button since we don't actually store the push notifications you sent due to privacy regulations.